# change text of antv s2 options, sort

Tags: reactjs, antv

I'm using antv s2, I have the following question, I'm trying to change the text of the content of the table, to sort either ascending or descending, but I can't find the option, does anyone know how to change it or what could be done to change that Chinese text to that I want

I attached an image of what I get[image]

https://s2.antv.vision/examples

I hope you can help me, or at least to remove the option to order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set the Language using the below code: use setLang() to set to English.

```
import { setLang, PivotSheet } from '@antv/s2'
setLang('en_US')
```

Reference:
https://github.com/antvis/S2/blob/ada5082d299357b1b38af7629a784e3d071e6b77/s2-site/docs/manual/basic/i18n.zh.md